# How can you access a set of photos with the iPhone SDK?

Tags: iphone, camera, image

I know that I can access the camera or show the image picker to the user, but what if I just wanted to pick 10 photos, randomly, from the images stored on the device with no user interaction?

Using UIImagePickerController gives me the ability to use the camera or the image picker, but how can I do this automatically, without user interaction?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is no way of accessing any files from any Apple app (or any other app for that matter) unless you use one of the classes provided by the SDK.

Answer (score 0):

I once wrote a simple browser app that starts at / and populates a UITableView with the contents of the directory.  It let me see what directories I could access, and what files I could access within those directories.  If you can find what you're looking for, help yourself to it's directory contents.  Otherwise, it may be hidden from you, inaccessible from your application's sandbox.